# What is the difference between partitioning and formatting a disk?

Tags: partitioning, formatting

I have formatted and partitioned many disks, many times, and while I know the tools and effects are different, I don't fully understand why both are necessary.

In short, partitioning seems to pertain to how a disk is divided up. But isn't that formatting too, as formatting determines how the space on the disk is actually used? All this happens above the operating system, which is actually the thing that keeps track of files. What is the exact relation between formatting and partitioning?

UPDATE: please see new question [Why does deleting a partition cause data to be lost?](https://superuser.com/questions/1162776/why-does-deleting-a-partition-cause-data-to-be-lost)

Answer (score 2):

Partitions specify boundaries of areas on the disk.

Formatting is creating a filesystem volume.  This does things like creating a table for storing filesystem volume objects (like files and directories), creating a root directory, and creating a volume label.

When you format (which means creating/initializing the filesystem volume), the typical method is for the new filesystem volume to take up the entire available space, which is either an entire partition or an entire disk.  (For example, an entire partition on an SSD or a hard drive, or an entire disk if using a floppy disk.)

Comment: That's what I thought, but given how if a partition is deleted the data becomes in-accessible, it must be more than just a boundary? That happened to me http://superuser.com/questions/1162743/restoring-drive-that-accidentally-had-partition-deleted-but-not-formatted/1162755#1162755

Comment: Hmm maybe I should have asked the question why does deleting the partition make files inaccessible

Comment: @Celeritas, that's actually a good separate question, and it would be tough to do justice to both it and the current question in one question.

Comment: ah crap and I can't delete this question now that it has answers

Comment: @Celeritas, if you thought to ask this question, chances are some other people will also have the same question.  Now there are some answers for them.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Partitioning is creating logical units of space on a drive, dividing the drive in one or more parts, and deciding how much space will be allocated to each part of the drive.

You can use all drive as one partition, you can create multiple equally sized parts, multiple partitions, or create smaller and bigger parts of the drive, have several partitions of different sizes.

Formatting is process of creating filesystems on those drive parts, and deciding which filesystem will be on which part, it is not deciding how much space to use but what type of addressing table is that partition going to use, size is determined during partitioning, and file system will fill the whole partition, when it is created.

You can for example divide a single drive in two parts, and then format one part of the drive as ntfs, to install Windows on it, while you format a second part of the drive as ext4 for example, and install Linux on it.

You can't put two different filesystems on one partition, you need to have a partition for each filesystem.

You can have a scenario in which a partition is not fully filled with a filesystem, but in that case partition was expanded after the filesystem was created, or file-system shrinked after initial creation, and you need to expand the filesystem to fill up the empty space, or reduce the partition to free empty space for different partition, as that empty space can't be used for a different filesystem, unless you remove it from a partition in question, and add it to some other partition.

Filesystem lies on top of the partition, partition is a container for filesystem, and when you are resizing partitions or filesystems you always need to first expand/shrink one, before doing the same to the second.

If you want to expand a filesystem, you first need to expand the partition, before you expand the filesystem, and when you want to reduce partition size, you need to first reduce the filesystem size, before reducing partition size.

Some partitioning tools, especially on Windows, will present filesystem/partition as one single unit to user, it will not clearly differentiate parition/filesystem layers to end user, and will automatically do resizing of filesystem, and then partition, of partition, and then filesystem, without cleary showing the user that those are two different layers of hard drive structure.

Answer (score 1):

A partition defines a portion (which can be all), of a physical drive as a container of a certain size and for a certain general type of use.

If its use is designated as swapfile, for example, the system will use and manage the partition's space directly; it won't be formatted.

If the partition is to be used to hold files, it needs a filesystem to manage the file infrastructure (keeping track of the pieces, providing a directory structure, holding metadata about the file characteristics, permissions, etc.).  Formatting creates the filesystem inside the partition.

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning this is simply a virtual division of a drive or disk into two or more volumes and defining how much space can be allocated to a particular volume of space within that drive.

Formatting, in short, can be defined as a the preparation of a drive for initial use, hence stating its file system.